# I need help to finish this, I am stock for the month. Sorry, there is a bit of french

Tags: python

Hello stackoverflow community!

I am stuck at finding the corresponding month to the highest or lowest price value in my txt file.

Example: the dates in my txt file are formatted this way (dd-mm-yyyy):

> 06-01-2020:127.0
>
> 03-02-2020:117.7
>
> 02-03-2020:118.0
>
> 06-04-2020:86.9
>
> 04-05-2020:94.1
>
> 01-06-2020:102.2
>
> 06-07-2020:110.5
>
> 03-08-2020:107.4
>
> 07-09-2020:106.9
>
> 05-10-2020:106.5
>
> 02-11-2020:102.1
>
> 07-12-2020:106.9

My function get_highest(essence_list) go through my txt file and return the highest value which is 127.0.

My function get_lowest(essence_list) go through my txt file and return the lowest value which is 86.9.

**I want to print the corresponding month to the highest and lowest value.**

Example: `get_highest(essence_list)` function returns 127.0. I want to print the corresponding month which is 01 and display it in this format : 01 = "January", 02 = "February",... 12="December".

Same for get_lowest(essence_list), returns 86.9 and the corresponding month is 04. If 04 then "April",etc.

I could then add this to my last lines of code,

```
print("The highest price of the year is:", get_highest(essence_list), "corresponding month name",)
```

Those are the lines :

```
# Display the highest price.
print("the highest price of the year is:", get_highest(essence_list), "corresponds to the month",**(I want to add the corresponding month here)**)

# Show the lowest price.
print("The lowest price of the year is:", get_lowest(essence_list), "corresponds to the month",**(I want to add the corresponding month here)**)
```

Thank you for the help guys!

```
# Open, read and close the file
monfichier = open('prixEssence.txt', 'r')
fichier = monfichier.readlines()
essence_list = fichier

# Creation of new list to separate values
Prix = []


# The get_price function accepts a string assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price. It returns the Price component as a float.
def get_price(str):
    # traitement:
    for prices in essence_list:
        prices = float(prices.split(':')[1])
        Prix.append(prices)
    return Prix


# Creation of new list to separate values
MM = []


# The get_month function accepts a string that is assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price. It returns the MM component as an int.
def get_month(str):
    # traitement:
    for months in essence_list:
        months = int(months.split('-')[1])
        MM.append(months)
    return MM


# The get_average function calculates the average price of gasoline for the year 2020. The essence_list parameter is a list of strings, where each string is assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price.
def get_yearly_average(essence_list):
    # Traitement
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    for value in get_price(str):
        # Assignation des valeurs
        count = count + 1
        sum = sum + value
        average = sum / count
    # Return the mean
    return round(average, 2)


# The get_highest function walks through the essence_list, showing the highest price of gasoline.
def get_highest(essence_list):
    # Traitement
    get_high = None
    for value in get_price(str):
        if get_high is None:
            get_high = value
        elif value > get_high:
            get_high = value
    return get_high


#The get_lowest function walks through the essence_list, displaying the lowest price for gasoline.
def get_lowest(essence_list):
    # traitement
    get_low = None
    for value in get_price(str):
        if get_low is None:
            get_low = value
        elif value < get_low:
            get_low = value
    return get_low

# Display the average price.
print("Le prix moyen est:", end=" ")
print(format(get_yearly_average(essence_list), '.2f'), sep='')

# Display the highest price.
print("The highest price of the year is:", get_highest(essence_list), "corresponds to the month",)

# Show the lowest price.
print("The lowest price of the year is:", get_lowest(essence_list), "corresponds to the month",)
```

Comment: That code is not correct.  You're using `str`, which you have not defined.  You are going to need to convert your input into a list of 2-element lists with date and price.  Then, you can find the max price, and search through the list to find the date that corresponds.

Answer (score 0):

You were already creating lists with all the prices and all the months, but you weren't using them.  So, have this return the max price, then look up that price in the prices list, and use the corresponding entry in the month list:

```
import calendar

# Open, read and close the file
monfichier = open('prixEssence.txt', 'r')
fichier = monfichier.readlines()
essence_list = fichier


# The get_price function accepts a string assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price. It returns the Price component as a float.
def get_price(str):
    # traitement:
    Prix = []
    for prices in essence_list:
        prices = float(prices.split(':')[1])
        Prix.append(prices)
    return Prix


# The get_month function accepts a string that is assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price. It returns the MM component as an int.
def get_month(str):
    # traitement:
    MM = []
    for months in essence_list:
        months = int(months.split('-')[1])
        MM.append(months)
    return MM


# The get_average function calculates the average price of gasoline for the year 2020. The essence_list parameter is a list of strings, where each string is assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price.
def get_yearly_average(prices):
    # Traitement
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    for value in prices:
        # Assignation des valeurs
        count = count + 1
        sum = sum + value
        average = sum / count
    # Return the mean
    return round(average, 2)


# The get_highest function walks through the essence_list, showing the highest price of gasoline.
def get_highest(prices):
    # Traitement
    get_high = 0
    for value in prices:
        if value > get_high:
            get_high = value
    return get_high


#The get_lowest function walks through the essence_list, displaying the lowest price for gasoline.
def get_lowest(prices):
    # traitement
    get_low = 1E9
    for value in prices:
        if value < get_low:
            get_low = value
    return get_low

Prix = get_price(essence_list)
MM = get_month(essence_list)

# Display the average price.
print("Le prix moyen est:", end=" ")
print(format(get_yearly_average(Prix), '.2f'), sep='')

# Display the highest price.
highest = get_highest(Prix)
idx = Prix.index(highest)
print("The highest price of the year is:", highest, "corresponds to the month",calendar.month_name[MM[idx]])

# Show the lowest price.
lowest = get_lowest(Prix)
idx = Prix.index(lowest)
print("The lowest price of the year is:", lowest, "corresponds to the month",calendar.month_name[MM[idx]])
```

Output:

```
Le prix moyen est: 107.18
The highest price of the year is: 127.0 corresponds to the month January
The lowest price of the year is: 86.9 corresponds to the month April
```

Note that, by using the `sum`, `min`, and `max` functions, you could reduce `get_yearly_average`, `get_highest` and `get_lowest` to one line each.

```
# The get_average function calculates the average price of gasoline for the year 2020. The essence_list parameter is a list of strings, where each string is assumed to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY: Price.
def get_yearly_average(prices):
    return round(sum(prices)/len(prices), 2)


# The get_highest function walks through the essence_list, showing the highest price of gasoline.
def get_highest(prices):
    return max(prices)

#The get_lowest function walks through the essence_list, displaying the lowest price for gasoline.
def get_lowest(prices):
    return min(prices)
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your fast and very clear answer! But, i can't use sum,min,max and import calender. My teacher doesn't want haha , so I have to find alternative solutions.

Comment: I assume you know how to build an array of month names.

Comment: Yes, but it's the how to look for it and if it matches then print the good month name ... I am having a hard time with this.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much Sir! Have a wonderful day !I am sorry if my questions sounds easy but I worked on this 3 days and it's finally getting there!